# In Power BI, is it possible to hold a column in a Measure variable?

Tags: powerbi, m

We have a slicer with the value "Local" and "USD".
[image: currency slicer]

Depending on the selection we want to use a different column of data for calculations.

This works.

```js
Billings Sum = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE(CurrencyPickerTable[Currency]) = "Local",
    SUM('BillingsTable'[Billings (local)]),
    SUM('BillingsTable'[Billings (USD)])
)
```

However, it's going to get more complicated because we want to also add a slicer for "Fiscal Year" and "Calendar Year" year.

If both possible selections are in the RETURN section there will be a bunch of repeated code.

Is it possible to put a column into a variable and use it later in the calculation?
This is my failing attempt.

```js
Billings Sum = 
var selectedCurrencyColumn = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE(CurrencyPickerTable[Currency]) = "Local", 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(BillingsTable, "local", [Billings (local)]), 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(BillingsTable, "USD", [Billings (USD)])
)

RETURN
SUM(selectedCurrencyColumn)
```

How can I get a column into the `currencyColumn` variable?

Comment: The way you attempted, not possible. To say what you need, we need sample data and your required output from them. But if I get your point, you wants to apply Date/FY filter on your measure "Billings Sum". If it is correct, not sure why you need second measure for that? Any sliced value will be automatically impact your measure "Billings Sum".

Comment: But you can store Table to a variable. You can try to generate a table for the first variable "selectedCurrencyColumn" by filtering data. Then you can do necessary Aggregation in the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible afaik, but you might obtain a nice formula using the SWITCH TRUE method and some variables to check the selection

```
[Billings Sum] =
VAR CurrencySelection =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( CurrencyPickerTable[Currency] )
VAR CalendarSelection =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( CalendarPickerTable[Calendar] )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        CurrencySelection = "Local"
            && CalendarSelection = "Calendar Year", [Billings (local)],
        CurrencySelection = "Local"
            && CalendarSelection = "Fiscal Year", [Billings (local) FC],
        CurrencySelection = "USD"
            && CalendarSelection = "Calendar Year", [Billings (USD)],
        CurrencySelection = "USD"
            && CalendarSelection = "Fiscal Year", [Billings (USD) FC],
        BLANK ()
    )
```

This assumes that you have a measure to cover each possible combination of the selections matrix (Currency and Calendar in this case), but if that's not the case you can also create some variables as measures or write the formula inside the switch.

Reference:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/optimizing-if-and-switch-expressions-using-variables/

Comment: Thanks. Writing the formulas inside the switch was the only way to make the approach work.